# rails disable development.log but still log to STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I disable the logging to logs/(env).log but still preserve rails logging to STDOUT? The correct answer works in in a vanilla rails 4 app running the latest stable version of rails, with no modifications of the Gemfile (i.e. no additional dependencies) and does not use /dev/null (only modifications to ruby code). Monkey patching allowed (encouraged?).

if it works in older versions of rails thats great but not required.

Log output should not be altered in any way, e.g:

```
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.257440 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.0ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.257504 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.0ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.261314 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.261366 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.270427 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (6.4ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.270466 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (6.4ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.273338 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.273367 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2015-02-20T07:54:35.273420 #64936]  INFO -- :   Rendered /Users/lsu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (22.8ms)
```

Answer (score 6):

To suppress output to log files, set the output stream of the configured logger to `nil`.

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(nil)
end
```

`rails server` will still log to `STDOUT`, but no log file is created.

Comment: `Logger.new(nil)` will disable `DEPRECATION WARNINGS` by Rails. Pass `STDOUT` instead of `nil` to show it in the console.

Answer (score 2):

You would add the following to your `config/environments/development.rb` file:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
ExampleApp::Application.configure do 
  ...
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.log_formatter = Logger::SimpleFormatter.new
  ...
end
```

Read more on [The Logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger).

Comment: this solution prepends the log output with a bunch of stuff like "I, [2015-02-19T10:46:22.566771 #73657]  INFO -- :".. updated question with clarification

Comment: So, what is your expected output.  Can you include an example in your question?

Comment: the expectation is that the log output is unaltered, the desired solution would simply disable the logging to the file (wherever that may be inside of rails) and simply leave the existing log to STDOUT as-is

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does exactly what you are asking for.  Did you restart your rails server after making this change?  All this line is doing is instead of logging to the default logger, it's outputting to STDOUT.

Comment: did you see my first comment? It prepends the log lines with "metadata" with the timestamp, loglevel, etc...

Comment: @quinn, please see updated code block.  Tested on a new Rails app.  Although I did not have to specify the `log_formatter` as Rails defaults to `ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter` itself.  With this change I do not see any output in `development.log` and there is no timestamps in the outputted log entries in STDOUT.

Comment: I just tested in a fresh rails v4.2.0 app, i got the same thing. the logs are being prepended. I added a snippet of the output into the question